# How to train LSTM model with multi-time series in timestamps

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, lstm

I have a problem, I don't know how to perform LSTM training in my case. I have flight data in the form of a time series, I have the complete route of the flight and what I need is to use this data to predict the time of arrival. But I don't understand very well how to make the prediction since in the examples I see they always make predictions seen 1 month, 1 year. And what I need, given a route that is not complete, is to say what time I estimate the plane will arrive.